# jquery plugin and a Click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this must be easy but I am failing to make it work. I Have a this from my plugin

```
(function($) {
$.fn.Update = function() {
   console.log("Clicked");
}; 
})(jQuery);
```

and this on the page where I want to use:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/my.Plugin.js">

</script>

$(function() {
    $(".btnUpdate").click(function() {
        //TODO: Add the function from the plugin
        Update();
    });        
});
```

but I am getting
    ReferenceError: update is not defined
and noticed that when the page load, I don't go inside the function, I only touch on the $.fn.update and move straight to the end.

Any help welcome

Comment: Try calling your function like this: `$().Update();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$.fn.Update = function() {...}` you add a new method to jQuery selected elements.

You can call that function using:

```
$.fn.Update();
```

or

```
$("...").Update();
```

Using `$(foo).Update()`, `$(foo)` will be `this` inside of the `Update` function.

---

You get *`Update is not defined`* error because you don't have any `Update` function (that is declared globally), but `$.fn.Update`.

Comment: Accepted as an answer as I think it is correct when adding an event/manipulating a DOM, It is not applicable to my situation. for anyone looking to use plugins inside the click of a button then $().Update did the trick for me.

Comment: @JackM If your plugin doesn't interact with DOM, you can simply attach it to `$`: `$.Update = function () {...}`. Then you will call it directly: `$.Update()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method from your own plugin.

You can either `bind` it to an element like `$("#some_element").Update();`

Read more here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot that it was using `$.fn` @Ben